# How to pass single method with multiple previleges to 'can?' method of cancan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I am using devise and cancan gem to manage authentication and permissions in my rails application. The application is about library management. I have defined methods inside ability.rb like:

```
def lend
  can :manage, Book
  can :manage, Transactions
end
```

Then in ability.rb, I have assigned permissions as

```
if user.role? == "librarian" 
  can lend
end
```

In the views, I can use `can?(:manage, Book)` or `can?(manage, Transaction)` for users with "librarian" role.

However, I want to be able to use `current_user.can?(:lend)`. I followed [this github page](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ability-for-Other-Users) to make can? method available inside user model. This allows me to use

```
current_user.can?(:manage, Book)
```

But, `current_user.can?(:lend)` results into `wrong number of arguments(1 for 2+)`. I have a feeling that I am missing a bit of intellect here. I tried google and the related post here but to no avail. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`can?` has two required arguments:

```ruby
def can?(action, subject, *extra_args)
```

Hence: `wrong number of arguments(1 for 2+)`

See [cancan/lib/cancan/ability.rb:56](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/1.6.10/lib/cancan/ability.rb#L56)

Also, in your `ability.rb` (below) there is neither an `action` nor a `subject` named `:lend`.  The method name is irrelevant to cancan.

```ruby
def lend
  can :manage, Book
  can :manage, Transactions
end

if user.role? == "librarian" 
  can lend
end
```